# getDefaultProps is not working using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use getDefaultProps method for the below example using react.js and I found it is not working for me:
HTML:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var RecentChangesTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < table className = 'table' > {
        this.props.children
      } < /table>);
    }
  });

RecentChangesTable.Heading = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var headingStyle = {
      backgroundColor: 'FloralWhite',
      fontSize: '19px'
    };
    return <th style = {
      headingStyle
    } > {
      this.props.heading
    } < /th>;
  }
});

RecentChangesTable.Headings = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var headings = this.props.headings.map(function(name, index) {
      return <RecentChangesTable.Heading key = {
        index
      }
      heading = {
        name
      }
      />
    });
    return <thead > < tr > {
      headings
    } < /tr></thead >
  }
});

RecentChangesTable.Row = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var trStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'aliceblue'
      }
      return <tr style = {
          trStyle
        } >
        < td > {
          this.props.changeSet.when
        } < /td> < td > {
      this.props.changeSet.who
    } < /td> < td > {
    this.props.changeSet.description
  } < /td> < /tr >
}
});

RecentChangesTable.Rows = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var rows = this.props.changeSets.map(function(changeSet, index) {
            return ( < RecentChangesTable.Row key = {
                index
              }
              changeSet = {
                changeSet
              }
              />);
            });
          return ( < tbody > {
              rows
            } < /tbody>)
          }
        });



      var App = React.createClass({
        getDefaultProps: function() {
          return {
            headings: ['When happened ', 'Who did it', 'What they change']
          };
        },
        render: function() {
          return ( < RecentChangesTable >
            < RecentChangesTable.Rows changeSets = {
              this.props.changeSets
            }
            /> < /RecentChangesTable > );
        }
      });


      var data = [{
        "when": "2 minutes ago",
        "who": "Jill Dupre",
        "description": "Created new account"
      }, {
        "when": "1 hour ago",
        "who": "Lose White",
        "description": "Added fist chapter"
      }];

      var headings = ['When', 'Who', 'Description'];
      var props = {
        headings: headings,
        changeSets: data
      };

      React.render( < App changeSets = {
          data
        }
        />, document.body);
```

Can anyone tell me is there I am missing here.

Comment: Do you mean `ReactDOM.render`? Also your `App` component returns `this.props.headings` but you never use it? Also your code is incredibly hard to read. Where did you get the idea to space stuff out like that?

Comment: You have defined getDefaultProps in App but never use it.

Comment: I tried all ways to read the getDefaultProps but it is not working for me here. Any code sample will be help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code as mentioned below and it worked for me:

```
var RecentChangesTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < table className = 'table' > {
        this.props.children
      } < /table>);
    }
  });

RecentChangesTable.Heading = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var headingStyle = {
      backgroundColor: 'FloralWhite',
      fontSize: '19px'
    };
    return <th style = {
      headingStyle
    } > {
      this.props.heading
    } < /th>;
  }
});

RecentChangesTable.Headings = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var headings = this.props.headings.map(function(name,index) {
      return <RecentChangesTable.Heading key={index} heading = {
        name
      }
      />
    });
    return <thead > < tr > {
      headings
    } < /tr></thead >
  }
});

RecentChangesTable.Row = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var trStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'aliceblue'
      }
      return <tr style = {
          trStyle
        } >
        < td > {
          this.props.changeSet.when
        } < /td> < td > {
      this.props.changeSet.who
    } < /td> < td > {
    this.props.changeSet.description
  } < /td> < /tr >
}
});

RecentChangesTable.Rows = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var rows = this.props.changeSets.map(function(changeSet,index) {
            return ( < RecentChangesTable.Row key={index} changeSet = {
                changeSet
              }
              />);
            });
          return ( < tbody > {
              rows
            } < /tbody>)
          }
        });



      var App = React.createClass({
                getDefaultProps:function(){
            return {
            headings:['When happened','Who did it','What they change']
          };
        },

          render: function() {
            return ( < RecentChangesTable >
              < RecentChangesTable.Headings headings = {
                this.props.headings
              }
              /> < RecentChangesTable.Rows changeSets = {
              this.props.changeSets
            }
            /> < /RecentChangesTable > );
        }
      });

    var data = [{
      "when": "2 minutes ago",
      "who": "Jill Dupre",
      "description": "Created new account"
    }, {
      "when": "1 hour ago",
      "who": "Lose White",
      "description": "Added fist chapter"
    }];

    var headings = ['When', 'Who', 'Description'];
    var props = {
      //headings: headings,
      changeSets: data
    }; 

    ReactDOM.render( < App {...props}/>,
      document.getElementById('container'));
```